# How to update a value after it is returned in python

Tags: python

Consider this piece of code, wondering would it be possible to return a value before it gets updated.

```
class A:

    def __init__(self):
         self.n = 0

    def get_next(self):
         return self.n++ # Return its current value. after it gets returned, update n. 

a = A()
a.get_next() # return 0
a.get_next() # return 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This'll work:

```
def get_next(self):
    old_value = self.n
    self.n += 1
    return old_value
```